# How long should I wait before applying sealant to pressure treated deck lumber?

Tags: wood

After reading several comments on how long to wait before applying a sealant, the recommendations were from 3 weeks to 2 years, some of the comments were from states other than where I live.

So does anyone know how long one should wait before applying sealant to pressure treated deck lumber in North Central Texas?

Comment: There are more factors than just what state you're in, which is why recommendations vary. Read the label on your preferred product and go with that. Voting to close as a multiple.